# magento custom layout update

Tags: php, html, css, magento

Does anybody know how I can call a stylesheet from my skin folder rather than it trying to point to my base path? I currently have

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addCss">
        <stylesheet>yourtheme/css/red.css</stylesheet>
        <params>media="screen"</params>
    </action>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ok I'm cracking up, it's cause the css file wasn't in my skin folder - I was just looking at the view source, obviously if it doesn't find the file it defaults to the base path- doh!